# I’m having troubles with the shared transitions plugin for xamarin forms. Will post link to the issue in the body

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

added the shared transition app shell to my app shell code and now whenever I navigate backwards I get

System.NotSupportedException "Unable to activate instance of type Plugin.SharedTransitions.Platforms.Android.SharedTransitionPageRenderer from native handle 0x7fe61ad9b4 (key_handle 0x45d1348)."

System.MissingMethodException " No constructor found for Plugin.SharedTransitions.Platforms.Android.SharedTransitionPageRenderer::.ctor(System.IntPtr, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership)"

Java.Interop.JavaLocationException "Exception of type 'Java.Interop.JavaLocationException' was thrown."

It is on any page I try to navigate backwards my code only has the shared transition shell implemented into it. I haven't even done the shared transitions I wanted to yet because there isn't a point to implement anything if I can't even go backwards.

https://github.com/GiampaoloGabba/Xamarin.Plugin.SharedTransitions/issues/69